# SQL full join priority

Tags: sql, join

Say you have 3 tables (tableA, tableB, tableC), each with an ID column and a Value column. Some of the tables' IDs match but some don't. 
If you do:

```
SELECT tableA.ID FROM tableA
FULL JOIN tableB ON (tableA.ID = tableB.ID)
FULL JOIN tableC ON (tableA.ID = tableC.ID)
```

Is this different from:

```
SELECT tableA.ID FROM tableA
FULL JOIN tableB ON (tableA.ID = tableB.ID)
FULL JOIN tableC ON (tableB.ID = tableC.ID)
```

Or:

```
SELECT Y.ID FROM
(SELECT tableA.ID FROM tableA
FULL JOIN tableB ON (tableA.ID = tableB.ID)) X
FULL JOIN tableC ON (X.ID = tableC.ID)) Y
```

??? Someone please explain if there is a difference. Thanks.

[Oracle SQL Developer version 4.02.15.21]

Comment: Your queries are syntactically incorrect.  You need to specify which `id` you want.  So, all are equivalent in the sense that all will return the same error, something to the effect that `id` is ambiguously defined.

Comment: All the 3 queries would give the same result. - An error for the ID column citing it as ambiguous. :)

Comment: @Blisskarthik, [do not use blockquotes and <br> tags for code](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5333973). We have rolled back your revision, but it should have been rejected

Comment: You'll need to change your SELECT to COALESCE(tableA.ID,tableB.ID,tableC.ID) [or appropriate variations thereof depending on query structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, here are all 3 statements, syntactically cleaned up:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID,c.ID)
FROM      tableA a
FULL JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
FULL JOIN tableC c ON a.ID = c.ID

SELECT COALESCE(a.ID,b.ID,c.ID)
FROM      tableA a
FULL JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
FULL JOIN tableC c ON b.ID = c.ID

SELECT COALESCE(X.ID,c.ID) 
FROM
( SELECT    COALESCE(a.ID ,b.ID) ID
  FROM      tableA a
  FULL JOIN tableB b ON a.ID = b.ID) X
FULL JOIN   tableC c ON X.ID = c.ID
```

Surprisingly, the syntax of the first statement produces duplicate values, but statements 2 and 3 work as advertised.

Edit: Upon further testing, statements 1 and 2 are prone to duplicates, depending on which tables overlap. Statement 3 seems to be the only solid approach.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d79c/6/0)

Comment: Thanks. So is the last one the only one that joins tableC to all of the combined tableA+tableB result without producing duplicates?

I want tableC to full join tables A and B on both of their IDs after they've been joined

Comment: also what is the purpose of coalesce here? selecting ID the way I've done above does not produce an error, and should grab the full column of IDs including all of the tables entries

Comment: Experiment with the SQLFiddle. If all 3 tables have a field called ID, using SELECT ID will throw an error as the engine doesn't know which table's ID to output.

Comment: Updated SQLFiddle with ID columns from each table output, so now you can really see what's happening with the Full Joins and Coalesces

Comment: i don't know how to use SQLFiddle lol I'm sorry. I click your link but it's blank, what am I missing? Or what do I do

Comment: why is the COALESCE() function used?